# What's the right code for duplicate records?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this form that saves participants. Here's the output.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiRN6.png]

As you can see in the image, all of the participants have the same name and the same number but have different email addresses, what I want to do is to prevent it from inserting the same record (same number and name but different email) even if it has a different email address (sorry for my bad explanation)

```
command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM participants_tbl WHERE firstname ='"+ txtFName.Text.Trim() +"'AND lastname='"+ txtLName.Text.Trim()+ "'AND middlename='" +txtMName.Text.Trim() + "'AND email='" + txtEmail.Text.Trim() + "'AND contact_no='" + txtContact.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
```

Comment: You can do this by creating the appropriate primary key for your database table. The following may be helpful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: set unique type for column of your data
see this link for more info:
https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-make-a-column-unique-in-sql/

Comment: You don't want to create SQL queries like that as it makes it vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Please research Prepared Statements

Comment: Make a composite unique key that will help you to maintain the data integrity and uniqueness property as @webrefer has already said above.